# How I can draw this figure representing a queue using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi could someone please help me to draw this figure in Tikz please.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. This doesn't really look very difficult. Why don't you show us what you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are Linux lover and I am a penguin...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rect/.style={draw,thin,fill=blue,minimum width=1em,
    minimum height=3.5em,alias=tmp},font=\sffamily,>={Latex[bend]}]
 \path[nodes=rect] node(r0){} node[below right=0em and 2em of tmp](r1){}
 foreach \i in {2,...,5} {node[right=1ex of tmp](r\i){}}
 node[below right=0em and 2em of tmp](r6){};
 \path[nodes={inner xsep=0pt}] 
    (r1.north west) node[above right]{Back}
    (r5.north east) node[above left]{Front};
 \draw[->](r0.south) to[out=-90,in=180] node[below left]{Enqueue} (r1.west);
 \draw[->](r5.east) to[out=0,in=90] node[above right]{Dequeue} (r6.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: je trouve que le pingouin est très gentil.

Comment: Thank you very much